# how to solve error when trying to connect DB in SQL SERVER using JDBC DRIVER

Tags: java, sql

Hello i have this issue trying to connecting  the Database, it seem's to be an error while the driver is connecting to the DB, i have the Controller Code , I am using `PreparedStatement` , this declaration its ok whit the 6.0.8 Version of the driver?

I post the `controller` Code. its something like this. i require some help. I found a Solution in my other post. Regards.

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controlador implements Initializable{

    ObservableList <Cliente> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   @FXML TableView<Cliente>  tablacliente;
   @FXML TableColumn<Cliente, String> nombrescol;
   @FXML TableColumn<Cliente,String > apellidoscol;
   @FXML TableColumn<Cliente, Integer>  clienteid;
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement=null;
   ResultSet rs=null;
   Connection Conexion=null;
   @FXML  private TextField nm;
    @FXML private TextField ap;
    @FXML private Button btn;


@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    clienteid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Cliente, Integer>("id_cliente"));
    nombrescol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Cliente, String>("nombres"));
     apellidoscol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Cliente, String>("apellidos"));
    agregar();
}

// connect main class to controller

public void conexion(){

    String query="select * from cliente";

    try {

        Conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "123");
        preparedStatement=Conexion.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);

        while ( rs.next() ) 
        {
        data.add(new Cliente(
                rs.getString("nombre"),
                rs.getString("apellido"),
                rs.getInt("id")
                ));
        tablacliente.setItems(data);
        }

        preparedStatement.close();
        rs.close();

        } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     if(Conexion!=null) {
         System.out.println("conexion exitosa");

     }
     if(Conexion==null) {
         System.out.println("no se conecto ");

     }
}

public void agregar() {
 String Nombre=nm.getText();
 String Apellido=ap.getText();
 String query="INSERT INTO CLIENTE (nombre,apellido)VALUES (?,?)";

 preparedStatement=null;

 try
 {
     preparedStatement=Conexion.prepareStatement(query);
     preparedStatement.setString(1, Nombre);
     preparedStatement.setString(2, Apellido);

 }
 catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
     try {
        preparedStatement.execute(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
   nm.clear();
   ap.clear();
   conexion();


}
}
```

this is the error's that i had trying to connect and insert the data into the database in SQL SERVER 2014.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=prueba
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controlador.agregar(Controlador.java:88)
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controlador.conexion(Controlador.java:51)
    at application.Controlador.agregar(Controlador.java:97)
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=prueba
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controlador.conexion(Controlador.java:56)
    at application.Controlador.agregar(Controlador.java:97)
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controlador.conexion(Controlador.java:51)
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=prueba
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controlador.conexion(Controlador.java:56)
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you added the `Jar` to the classpath?

Comment: does not look related to fx